# My syntax is off and I can't quite get it, PHP and HTML, simple echo statement

Tags: php, html

It has to do with me using PHP variables and strings inside the echo.

Here it is:

INVALID because of all the '' and ""s something gets messed up somewhere

```
 echo '<td id="'.$email['email_id'].' style='.'text-align: left'.'"><button onclick="document.getElementById('."AttachmentModal".').style.display='."block".'"><i class="fontello-attach-1"></i></button></td>';
```

VALID EXAMPLE, notice how this one isn't in an echo statement? The above one needs to be echo'd though I think.

```
<th style="text-align: left"><button onclick="document.getElementById('AttachmentModal').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black"><i class="fontello-attach-1"></i></button></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by taking it out of php (with ?>) and then coding in HTML and putting it back into php after I was finished. I also reinstated php with () in the middle of the html when needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the corrected

```
echo '<td id="'.$email['email_id'].'" style="text-align: left">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById("AttachmentModal").style.display='."block".'">
        <i class="fontello-attach-1"></i>
    </button>
</td>';
```

Comment: Thanks, I had figured it out and posted my own answer but I appreciate you taking the time to correct the syntax.

But actually I just tested it and this answer is not sufficient either, for getElementByID() it doesn't like "AttachmentModal" I believe it needs to be single quotes not double for HTML.